# Can I install wheel package in buildroot?

Tags: python, buildroot, mozilla-deepspeech

I want to install deepspeech on my embedded device (don't worry about power requirements, I intend to deal with that later).

However I failed several times at installing it. For what I've seen it is because there is only wheel files available for this package and I don't have python wheel on my device. Here are the available packages:

[packages availables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfC22.png)

So my questions are:
1) for an embedded device, which of these packages is the best ?
2) How do I install wheel on my device ? Like any other python package
3) Do I have to change anything in my .mk file or the config.in ? Here is the files:

.mk:

```
################################################################################
#
# python-deepspeech
#
################################################################################

PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_VERSION = 0.4.1
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_SOURCE = deepspeech-$(PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_VERSION)-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_SITE = https://pypi.python.org/packages/08/57/1c78063f8525aecbfa4a6122e1044e8128d4413ee407c14e0ec05fcbdebe
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_DEPENDENCIES = python
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_SETUP_TYPE = setuptools
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_LICENSE = MPL-2.0
PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH_LICENSE_FILES = LICENSE

$(eval $(python-package))
```

Config.in:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DEEPSPEECH
    bool "python-deepspeech"
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON
    help
        Config file for normal deepspeech.
```

Answer (score 2):

Buildroot doesn't provide a way to install wheel "binaries" at the moment. However, a `wheel` file is just a zip archive with some additional metadata, so it is possible to extract it and install manually.

Alternatively, it should be possible to install it with `pip` on the target.